# Any chance to use two matrices in a linear model

Tags: r, matrix, lm

I was wondering, if it is possible to use two matrices in a linear model as the independent and response variables in such a way, that column-pairs are used for the model calculation.

Let's say, the two matrices are called x and y, then I would like to calculate

```
lm(y[, 1] ~ x[, 1])
lm(y[, 2] ~ x[, 2])
lm(y[, 3] ~ x[, 3])
etc,
```

but all in one call.

What I've tried is

```
# Make two example matrices
x <- matrix(seq(1, 100), nrow = 10)
y <- matrix(seq(1, 100), nrow=10)

# First try
mod1 <- lm(y ~ x)
```

This only calculates linear models for all columns of y with the first column of x.

Another ideas was to use apply()

```
# Second try
mod2 <- apply(x, 2, function(x)(lm(y ~ x)))
```

This calculates linear models for all columns of y with all columns of x.
That is a bit too much, as I only wanted linear models for column pairs.

I could simply use a for-loop

```
mod_list <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    mod_list[[i]] <- lm(y[, i] ~ x[, i])
}
```

This, at least, calculates the pair-wise models.

So. **Would it be possible to use two matrices and calculated the models for the column pairs without using a for-loop?**

**Bonus question**: Is there a way to use the above calculated model list in a predict() function call and give it a matrix as newdata?
And yes. Use the first column of the newdata with the first model, etc.

I guess I will be stuck with something like

```
predicted <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
new_x <- matrix(seq(201, 300), nrow = 10)

for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    mod <- lm(y ~ x, data = data.frame(x = x[, i], y = y[, i]))
    predicted[, i] <- predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x = new_x[, i]))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Map`.

```
res <- Map(function(y, x) lm(y ~ x), as.data.frame(x), as.data.frame(y))
stopifnot(identical(as.numeric(res[[4]]$coe), as.numeric(lm(y[,4] ~ x[,4])$coe)))
```

And `mapply` for `predict` that gives the desired matrix format.

```
res2 <- t(mapply(function(k, l) predict(k, newdata=list(x=l)), res, asplit(new_x, 2)))
res2
#       1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
# V1  201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210
# V2  211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220
# V3  221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230
# V4  231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240
# V5  241 242 243 244 245 246 247 248 249 250
# V6  251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258 259 260
# V7  261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270
# V8  271 272 273 274 275 276 277 278 279 280
# V9  281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290
# V10 291 292 293 294 295 296 297 298 299 300

stopifnot(identical(predict(res[[1]], newdata=list(x=new_x[,1])), res2[1,]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and for getting the "Bonus question" right.

Answer (score 2):

`lapply` should work:

```
lms <- lapply(1:3, function(z) lm(y[, z] ~ x[, z]))
```

Comment: Thank you the answer. Your code works perfectly. But I accepted @jay.sf answer, because he answered the "Bonus Question" as well.